# Odin. Unplugged target while flashing

Tags: odin, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I assumed something was wrong because I waited about 20 minutes and the process hadn't completed, nor did it look like anything was active. Apparently, something was and now my Samsung Epic Touch 4G will not boot into either odin mode or cwm. The only thing I get is the blue power indicator, which will blink once after a couple seconds and then go steady again.

Have I bricked my phone or is there something I can do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most often the phone simply recognizes that the flash needs to be completed, and refuses to enter most modes until it is.  So, first check and see if Odin will see the phone regardless of what's on the screen.  Otherwise:

Remove the battery, then re-insert and try to get into Download Mode again.  If that fails, then remove the battery and, while holding the key combo for Download Mode, re-insert the battery.

If that fails, plug into USB and try both of the above.

If that fails, try all 4 of the above with different key combinations.  The most common that might trigger something:

1. Home + VolDown + Power
2. Home + VolUp + Power
3. VolDown + VolUp + Power
4. VolDown + Power
5. VolUp + Power

Comment: Thanks... all of those options failed though.

Comment: @Rick In that case, you should probably try a [jig](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1331782).

Comment: Most importantly, ***don't panic*** before you've tried all of these options.  I panicked yesterday when this happened (I mean, I really panicked!), but after I removed the battery and waited a short while, it returned to download mode and I was able to proceed.