# Using Odin to flash a custom rom

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Nearly bricked my Samsung Epic Touch 4G. Managed to boot into Odin Mode with a USB jig. I'm back where I started now and need to re-evaluate what to do next.

The phone is rooted, won't see the SD Card or Internal anything. My only option is using Odin to get a custom ROM back on there. Can someone point me to a step by step? My last attempt at this led me to having to work with the USB jig to get another crack at it.

Thanks!

Comment: I merged this account with the account that asked [the other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15367/odin-unplugged-target-while-flashing).  You should register if you want to keep control of your questions :).  Glad to hear the jig helped though.

Comment: Actually, now it wont boot at all, even with the jig. But if I can't fire it up, even with the jig, I'm assuming Sprint can't either... thanks for your advice though. A good one to bookmark.

Comment: And I merged the account that left a comment as an answer. @Rick, I suggest you actually register instead of leaving a trail of low-reputation, unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to Odin a stock (or nearly stock) ROM after a softbrick.  [This guide on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282418) looks pretty good and includes a pre-rooted but largely stock ROM that should work for you.  If step 4 fails, disconnect and reconnect your phone to the PC; if it still fails, reboot the phone and try again.