# Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000 froze during firmware upgrade

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I accessed Samsung Kies and a screen message said that there was a firmware upgrade needed. I followed the screen prompt exactly and during the update a drop down message came up saying that there was a problem and to disconect the phone from the pc,remove battery and switch on again. The phone screen had a large triangle saying "Do not disconnect the phone during upgrade" I left the phone connected  but still the notice showed to disconnect the phone.I disconnected the phone as stated and removed the battery,then reinserted the battery and switched on the phone.All I got was a black screen with a phone icon - a yellow triangle with an exclamation marke init and an icon of a computer screen. 
Now all I get on the phone are the icons as just stated. Removing the battery and leaving it disconnected for 10 minutes before switching on only gerts those icons again.
In Kies,it still shows "Connect a device" 
Any idea how I can sort this problem out ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is the same as in my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15367/odin-unplugged-target-while-flashing/15370#15370): Try different button combinations to get into Download Mode, then try the update.  If the update doesn't work in Download Mode try again from the phone's normal booted-up state.

Comment: I tried these but nothing changes. Still get the phone icon - yellow triangle warningand computer icon on the screen.