# Samsung Galaxy GT-S5300B dead / bricked (?)

Tags: samsung, unbricking

I own a Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300B) and, last week, I mistakenly erased a partition issuing the command:

```
cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 > /dev/zero
```

(It was either that or /proc/mmcblk0p1, I can't remember o.O)

Now, my phone is dead. It doesn't turn on at all, in either download, recovery or any other mode (PS: It has no fastboot mode, as it appears - it's a cheaper Samsung smartphone). I've tried using a "USB Jig", kind of outta nowhere, just to see what happened, but it remains dead :/ If I plug it to a power source, either usb data cable or the charger, it does get warm, like the battery was charging, but it won't turn on by clicking the turn on/off button, no way... :S

Does anybody know how to fix such thing? I run Linux Mint 13 (but it's the same in other Linux distros or Windows) and lsusb will return:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b044 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Acer CrystalEye Webcam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
```

No Samsung ..., like there was before, or anything at all =/ The webcam, logitech and the ms transceiver are connected to my comp, so neither one of those is the phone hehe.

I have this on /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules:

```
# Samsung
SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, SYSFS{idVendor}==”04e8″, MODE=”0666″
```

Does anybody know if cracking the phone open will be any good to do anything? I don't have a RIFF Box or that kind of stuff, but I really don't want to send it to Samsung repair service unecessarily...

Thanks for you time already! If anyone has an idea, I'm most ready listening!

Comment: Have you tried getting into Odin mode?  Most Samsung devices don't use Fastboot.  See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/15370/1465

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look good I'm afraid.  You would need to be able to see 'something' relating to the phone from a 'lsusb' command to be able to use odin to recover your device without cracking it open.

You've probably already seen this, but it looks like the [JTagBox](http://www.jtagbox.com/jtag-news/riff-jtag-samsung-gts5300-galaxy-pocket-unbrick-dead-boot-repair-supported/) is your best bet.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man I was afraid that (JTag way) was the only option, but at this point I'm glad there IS an option, hehe. I've actually just sent my device to Samsung's repair service in town today, but I guess that's what they'll do over there (I'll see if I can find out in a week or so and I'll write the details underneath my post if I can). Thanks a lot!